# Passing multiple params in react-router-dom like reactnavigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-router-dom

Well, I'll get to the point with this, and I have a problem passing parameters to the browsing history
For those with experience in reactnavication, you will know how easy it is to pass multiple parameters in the form of an object.

now the problem I have is that the following block

```
goToChat = (chat) =>
  const { params } = this.props.route;
  const post = params && params.post ? params.post : ""
  const anotherParam = params && params.anotherParams ? params.anotherParams : ""
  ...
  if (chat) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate(CHAT_ROUTE, { chat, param, anotherParam, ... })
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

I have to make it work in a history.push with React-router-dom,
but I haven't found a way to do it
this is what i improvised

```
goToChat = (chat) =>
  const { params } = this.props.match;
  const post = params && params.post ? params.post : ""
  const anotherParam = params && params.anotherParams ? params.anotherParams : ""
  ...
  if (chat) {
    this.props.history.push(`${CHAT_ROUTE}/${chat}/, post, anotherParam, ... }`)
  } else {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm close to finding the solution with that attempt but, i need find a solution for this problem...

Comment: No, you can't do that. Do not waste your time.

Comment: ok, do you have a solution for this problem? any suggestion is good...

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can pass multiple params !

First you need that :

```
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
```

And after for example :

```
  let history = useNavigate();

  const yourEventCliked = (object1, object2) => {
   history("/Your URL to redirect/", {
    state: { param1: object1, param2: object2},
    });
  };
```

The goal here is to define state and give to it the params... very simple :)

Hope it helped !